Node unable to verify the first certificate
Suddenly my Node environments start not to install packages and they are freezing in idealTree:my-app : sill idealTree buildDeps
I tried npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global but did not work,
I had to use npm set strict-ssl false to make it work (I am not sure if it's safe?)
And then I started to getting this error as I am running dev server
 Error: unable to verify the first certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
    code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'



Environment:
Node 21.6.1
Nextjs 14.1.0
React 18.2.0
NPM 10.2.4
Does anyone see the same? An in general why this is happening without changing dependencies?

Does this answer your question? Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs

Same problem occured for me today "npm set strict-ssl false" didn't helped

Next.js also having trouble making API calls, basically my Login system does not work

Not sure if it's your case but looks very similar to what I started encountering around the same time as you (not only for npm but also for webpack-dev-server proxy and other things). Only now I managed to find out that it got broken after yesterday's update of ESET NOD32 Antivirus. There's already a report about it - https://forum.eset.com/topic/40702-eset-ssl-protection-produces-an-invalid-certificate-chain-for-nodejs-apps/.
The permanent solution will probably come from a NOD32 update but we'll see.
Solution for now is to turn off Enable HTTPS traffic scanning switcher in the settings to make NOD32 not scan communicating over SSL/TLS. Alternatively you can add particular apps into the ignore list if you still want to keep it scanning.

P.S. npm set strict-ssl false is an unsafe workaround for npm specifically and it's usually not the root of this kind of problems so it's better to set it back to true.

You are a life saver THANKS!
I had disabled NOD32 but apparently it did not work I had to go to setting,
Thanks again!

Made my day :)  thanks ! Disabling the firewall was not enough – __

Thank you so much for posting this!
I killed a whole afternoon searching for the problem and then a working solution.

Ah, finally. That's a lot of hours wasted on ESET basically breaking all https connections outside of the browser.

Can confirm, started for me today in all node applications and axios fetching. The same toggle solved it for me but with Eset Internet Security. Took me half the day finding this thread, thank you!

Our Azure deployment pipeline also broke, while trying to download secrets from the key-vault in the variable groups. This did the trick

Not me who created these instructions but apparently you can convert the Eset SSL cert and add it as an extra Node cert. I have not tested it myself.
https://github.com/the-last-byte/ESET-NPM-Breakage-Fix

I tried just now - this didn't work for me. I tried setting both setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS converted.cer /m and also npm config set cafile converted.cer.

Thanks a ton @Paintoshi. Worked like a charm. I spent almost a week to find solution.

A solution might be to add an exception for Node in the SSL protection rules of ESET. See: https://github.com/SillyTavern/SillyTavern/issues/2100#issuecomment-2063231168

Apart from turning off "https traffic scanning" it also worked as you said adding node to the web access protection excluded applications, in my case c:\users<user>\appdata\roaming\nvm\v18.17.1\node.exe since I use the nvm manager with a specific version
