NPM throws UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE error when installing vite
I am trying to run npm install @vitejs/plugin-react am facing this error help please
I want to run to run npm run dev. It require me to install @vitejs/plugin-react then when i try to install it give me the error:

UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-toolbelt/-/ts-toolbelt-9.6.0.tgz failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate


Check out the answer here in case you use nod32 antivirus - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78343601/node-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate/78347970#78347970
